# make first column of datagridview auto generate number?

Tags: c#

i have a windows form in c# on this form i have a datagridview named datagridview1 and i use this code to bind datagridview1 from a table datagridview1

```
ad = new OracleDataAdapter("select BORROWER_NAME,BORROWER_CODE,BOOK_CODE
                        from BORROWED_BOOK order by BORROWER_NAME", connection);
ad.Fill(ds, "BORROWED_BOOK");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["BORROWED_BOOK"];
bs.DataSource = ds.Tables["BORROWED_BOOK"];
dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["BORROWED_BOOK"]);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "name";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "b_code";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "book_code";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 90;`
```

i don't have a problem with bind the datagridview... Know when i bind the datagridview it beggin binding from the first index, my question is i want to make binding beggin from the second index to make the first index an auto generate number?

Comment: What you mean by `auto generate number`?

Comment: Did you just want the `DataGridView` to display the `number` or do you want it in your underlying `DataSet`? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: see this image http://oi57.tinypic.com/2z5vpsm.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's better to make row's header to display auto-incremented value?

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(comboBox2.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

 if (dataGridView1 != null){

   for (int count = 0; (count <= (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)); count++){
       dataGridView1.Rows[count].HeaderCell.Value = string.Format((count + 1).ToString(), "0");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to make row's header to display auto-incremented value?

```
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += (o, e) =>
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index + 1).ToString();
    };
```

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language, so I can't understand you.

Comment: what do you mean by make row's header to display auto-incremented value?

Comment: @honar.cs I meant to display the desired values in the headers column instead of in the first column. The headers column located to the left of the first column and typically has a gray background.

Comment: @Dmitry ... thank you i know this and i do this ... but this way is not good for me

Comment: @HenkHolterman The `foreach` loop iterates through *all* the rows, and I've never seen a hole in the rows indices. Additionally, I've tried this code several times previously and nothing criminal had happened.